# Encoding and decoding numpy.array to base64. Why is necessary to use numpy.frombuffer?

Tags: python-3.x, base64, decode, encode

Please consider, the following code:

```
import base64
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1,2]).astype('float32')

arrayencode64 = base64.b64encode(array)

arraydecode64 = base64.b64decode(arrayencode64)

ARRAY = np.frombuffer(arraydecode64, dtype='float32')

print(array)
print()
print(arrayencode64)
print()
print(arraydecode64)
print()
for el in arraydecode64:
    print(el)
print()
print(ARRAY)
```

**Question 1:** I would like to understand why, after to apply **base64.b64decode**, I do not retrieve the original object? I mean, why it need to be read with **np.frombuffer** with the type specified?

Because, I was expecting to obtain the target object (the numpy.array that is bind in the array variable) just after the application of **base64.b64decode**.

**Question 2:** When I print the variable **arraydecode64** with the **for loop** I got a sequence of number. What exactly they mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) all that `base64.b64decode` does is take a string and return a byte object. `np.frombuffer` then takes those bytes and creates and array. `base64` doesn't know how `numpy` represents bytes, and has no idea what an array is.